# Trace of Ricci flow equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

The Ricci flow equation as is known is given as:

$\partial_t g_{ij} = -2R_{ij}$.

If I take the trace/contract the indices of both sides, does this imply that:

$\partial_t g = -2R$,

where $g$ is the trace of the metric tensor, and $R$ is the Ricci curvature scalar?

Thank you.

Comment: The trace of the metric tensor is the dimension of the manifold. If that were true you'd get $R=0$ (So, in general, 'no'.)

Comment: Hi Thomas. Thanks for your answer. But then, what of the operation to multiply both sides by say $g^{ij}$?

Answer (score 3):

To take the trace of the Ricci tensor you are using the metric, so you need to be a little bit more careful: the correct expression is

$$ g^{ij} \partial_t g_{ij} = -2R.$$

Since $g^{ij}$ is varying in time you cannot replace the LHS by $\partial_t(g^{ij} g_{ij}) = \partial_t n=0$.

Comment: Hello. Okay, thank you that is very helpful!